# how to create .ipa file from Corona SDK

Tags: app-store, coronasdk, ipa

Please tell me how to create .ipa file instead of .app file in Corona SDK? and how to submit Corona Application in Appstore?

Answer (score 10):

I got a solution for creating .`ipa file` while creating build file from `Corona`. 
Steps are given below -

- **Step 1** - Create a .app file
- **Step 2** - Create a folder with name "Payload"
- **Step 3** - Compress the "Payload" folder and rename it to your file name.ipa
  from "Payload.zip".

Comment: And then what? how to actually upload it to itunes connect? I can't believe the Corona docs doesn't explain this process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go Corona Simulator -> File -> Build ->iOS

[image]

If you are going to get the build with distribution profile, corona will create compressed file for you so you can download it directly with application loader.

Comment: Corona creates `.app` builds, not `.ipa`.

Answer (score -3):

You need to have paid version of corona and you should use macOS. When you have those, the rest is easy