# Where is .ipa file on corona sdk

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

i builded ios on corona SDK

saved app.dSYM file and .app file , not want it

Need .ipa file , need upload my app on app store

There files

[image]

photo2

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create .ipa file from Corona SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826646/how-to-create-ipa-file-from-corona-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You should get a zip file after the build. Just change its suffix to .ipa.